# Apache URL redirect within same domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a site with URL abc.com. Now what I want is whenever that URL is being hit in browser it should redirect to www.abc.com/index.jsp. How this can be done using apache ?

Here's what I have done:

> VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ```
> ProxyRequests off
> ProxyPreserveHost On
>     <Proxy *>
>             Order deny,allow
>             Allow from all
>     </Proxy>
>     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
> ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/
>
> # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
> # alert, emerg.
> LogLevel error
>
> <Location />
>             Options +ExecCGI
>             AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>             AuthType basic
>             AuthName "private area"
>             AuthUserFile  "/etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd"
>             Require valid-user    </Location> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your .htaccess in the root of the page

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

can also use this at the end of your vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: should i put .htaccess inside /etc/httpd/conf

Comment: Ok. I think I have a virtual host setup over here. I have tomcat application and on above that we have apache installed. We are using virtual host for proxy pass and proxy pass reverse. What will be the location in that case ?\

Comment: is the tomcat application inside a WAR or a folder?

Comment: its inside Folder.

Comment: in that case add the .htaccess with the content above into that folder

Comment: Well I have this entries inside virtual host entry in httpd.conf file:  ServerName abc.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{abc.com} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{abc.com}/$1 [R=301,L] but it is redirecting to www.//

Comment: I think maybe you should use my edit in the answer above. add it to the end of your httpd.conf file and delete the other stuff you just added

Comment: You mean I need to put those entries outside <VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost> tag ?

Comment: yes. with this you add a new vhost that rewrites to your other vhost

Comment: And do I need to replace HTTP_HOST with my values in your above answer?

Comment: no. you don't need to replace them. it's an internal apache variable

Comment: ;-( It is redirecting to www.//

Comment: can you please add your <VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost> with the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to your question? maybe my answer isn't playing nicely with that

Comment: Edited the question with entries. Inside that virtual host entries I am adding what you have provided. I tried adding it outside too.

Comment: I made it working by adding below entries inside virtual host: RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301] but only thing is I am getting / at the end which should not come.

Comment: I wanted to implement one more redirect - If it is www.abc.com then redirect to www.abc.com/index.jsp along with the above one working. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: add RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.abc.com/index.jsp [L,R=301] instead of RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.abc.com [L,R=301]

Comment: Yeah but it should work with www and without www for the redirect rule www.abc.com/index.jsp